# iOS 8: An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController, Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Complete logs from my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` for iOS 8:

> ---STARTED---
>   --------I
>   --------I
>   --------I
>   ---FINISHED---
>   2016-02-18 10:42:22.433 POSowner[9784:66814] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:1623
>   2016-02-18 10:42:22.440 POSowner[9784:66814] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
>   ---STARTED---
>   --------D
>   --------D
>   --------D
>   ---FINISHED---

And for iOS 9:

> ---STARTED---
>   --------D
>   --------D
>   --------D
>   --------I
>   --------I
>   --------I
>   ---FINISHED---

And this is my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
//MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    print("---STARTED---")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        fallthrough
    case .Move:
        tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        print("--------I")
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Delete:
        print("--------D")
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Update:
        print("--------U")
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? PBOTableViewCell {
            updateCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    case .Move:
        print("--------M")
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        }
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    print("---FINISHED---")
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

and `UITableViewDataSourceDelegate`:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var numberOfSections = 0

    if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
        numberOfSections = sections.count
    }

    return numberOfSections
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let workday = workDayObjectForSection(section)
    return workday.worktimes.count
}

private func workDayObjectForSection(section: Int) -> PBOUserWorkDay {

    let sections: NSArray? = fetchedResultsController.sections!
    let sectionInfo = sections?.objectAtIndex(section) as? NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    let workdays = sectionInfo?.objects as! [PBOUserWorkDay]

    return workdays[0]
}
```

It happens **ONLY** on iOS 8. Any workarounds? **Eaxctly the same action** on iOS 9 works like a charm. And **EVERY TIME** it doesnt work on iOS 8.

Comment: Are you sure that the number of items you are editing is correct ? I have the same issue several times, and it was a logical error in my new data insertion

Comment: @bobby, I updated the question. If number of items wouldnt be correct, it wouldnt work on iOS 9. I can put more code if you need...

Comment: so you are saying that using the same data (exactly the same data) on iOS9 you have no crash, right?

Comment: I assume you are using Core Data, and Core Data for iOS9 has new features like unicity. So it may work on iOS 9 because FatchController detects that your are just editing an entry, and iOS 8 fail cause it thinks that your are adding a new one, but you aren't

Comment: yes, exactly the same data, and no crash on ios 9. Tested it hard. Of course I use core data. You may be right... any ideas how to fix this? I can try...

Comment: It looks like you are right, because I do not add any new rows there, only update them...

Comment: What is `workDayObjectForSection(section)`? Is there a special reason that you don't use the "usual" boilerplate code in the numberOfRowsInSection method, as e.g. documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, I've faced in the past. Please try the code below, maybe it helps.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    switch (type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: {
            // your code
        } break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            // your code
        } break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            // your code
        } break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: {
            // BUG: Move is called where Update is expected
            if ([indexPath compare:newIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
                // object is not moved, so perfrom the same logic as for NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

                // your code
            }
            else {
                // object is moved, actually

                // your code
            }
        } break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I could not remember where on SO I found the solution / thoughts in right direction.